# svg not showing up/ weird scaling

Tags: html, css, svg

Heads up I'm a beginner on coding.

I have been trying to make a portfolio type of website to practice my coding with *HTML* and *CSS*, I wanted to use 2 *SVGs* at the bottom of the page but I ran into some problem. Whenever I use `position: relative;` on both of the *SVG*, they would not appear on the page, but whenever I reload my page `SVG` can be seen for a slight second before going away.

The only way I managed to make it work is through making them `position: absolute;`, however it will create a problem when window is re-scaled.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjtyR.png) is what I want the website to look like.

```css
#ig {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 37%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.ig {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 17%;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
}

.twitter {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 37%;
  margin-left: 59%;
}

.handle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 9%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg
  id="ig"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="32"
  height="32"
  viewBox="0 0 32 32"
>
  <title>instagram1</title>
  <path
    d="M16 2.881c4.275 0 4.781 0.019 6.462 0.094 1.563 0.069 2.406 0.331 2.969 0.55 0.744 0.288 1.281 0.638 1.837 1.194 0.563 0.563 0.906 1.094 1.2 1.838 0.219 0.563 0.481 1.412 0.55 2.969 0.075 1.688 0.094 2.194 0.094 6.463s-0.019 4.781-0.094 6.463c-0.069 1.563-0.331 2.406-0.55 2.969-0.288 0.744-0.637 1.281-1.194 1.837-0.563 0.563-1.094 0.906-1.837 1.2-0.563 0.219-1.413 0.481-2.969 0.55-1.688 0.075-2.194 0.094-6.463 0.094s-4.781-0.019-6.463-0.094c-1.563-0.069-2.406-0.331-2.969-0.55-0.744-0.288-1.281-0.637-1.838-1.194-0.563-0.563-0.906-1.094-1.2-1.837-0.219-0.563-0.481-1.413-0.55-2.969-0.075-1.688-0.094-2.194-0.094-6.463s0.019-4.781 0.094-6.463c0.069-1.563 0.331-2.406 0.55-2.969 0.288-0.744 0.638-1.281 1.194-1.838 0.563-0.563 1.094-0.906 1.838-1.2 0.563-0.219 1.412-0.481 2.969-0.55 1.681-0.075 2.188-0.094 6.463-0.094zM16 0c-4.344 0-4.887 0.019-6.594 0.094-1.7 0.075-2.869 0.35-3.881 0.744-1.056 0.412-1.95 0.956-2.837 1.85-0.894 0.888-1.438 1.781-1.85 2.831-0.394 1.019-0.669 2.181-0.744 3.881-0.075 1.713-0.094 2.256-0.094 6.6s0.019 4.887 0.094 6.594c0.075 1.7 0.35 2.869 0.744 3.881 0.413 1.056 0.956 1.95 1.85 2.837 0.887 0.887 1.781 1.438 2.831 1.844 1.019 0.394 2.181 0.669 3.881 0.744 1.706 0.075 2.25 0.094 6.594 0.094s4.888-0.019 6.594-0.094c1.7-0.075 2.869-0.35 3.881-0.744 1.050-0.406 1.944-0.956 2.831-1.844s1.438-1.781 1.844-2.831c0.394-1.019 0.669-2.181 0.744-3.881 0.075-1.706 0.094-2.25 0.094-6.594s-0.019-4.887-0.094-6.594c-0.075-1.7-0.35-2.869-0.744-3.881-0.394-1.063-0.938-1.956-1.831-2.844-0.887-0.887-1.781-1.438-2.831-1.844-1.019-0.394-2.181-0.669-3.881-0.744-1.712-0.081-2.256-0.1-6.6-0.1v0z"
  ></path>
  <path
    d="M16 7.781c-4.537 0-8.219 3.681-8.219 8.219s3.681 8.219 8.219 8.219 8.219-3.681 8.219-8.219c0-4.537-3.681-8.219-8.219-8.219zM16 21.331c-2.944 0-5.331-2.387-5.331-5.331s2.387-5.331 5.331-5.331c2.944 0 5.331 2.387 5.331 5.331s-2.387 5.331-5.331 5.331z"
  ></path>
  <path
    d="M26.462 7.456c0 1.060-0.859 1.919-1.919 1.919s-1.919-0.859-1.919-1.919c0-1.060 0.859-1.919 1.919-1.919s1.919 0.859 1.919 1.919z"
  ></path>
</svg>
<p class="ig">annoying_fly</p>
<svg
  class="twitter"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="24"
  height="24"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
>
  <title>twitter</title>
  <path
    d="M20.833 5.262c-0.186 0.242-0.391 0.475-0.616 0.696-0.233 0.232-0.347 0.567-0.278 0.908 0.037 0.182 0.060 0.404 0.061 0.634 0 5.256-2.429 8.971-5.81 10.898-2.647 1.509-5.938 1.955-9.222 1.12 1.245-0.361 2.46-0.921 3.593-1.69 0.147-0.099 0.273-0.243 0.352-0.421 0.224-0.505-0.003-1.096-0.508-1.32-2.774-1.233-4.13-2.931-4.769-4.593-0.417-1.084-0.546-2.198-0.52-3.227 0.021-0.811 0.138-1.56 0.278-2.182 0.394 0.343 0.803 0.706 1.235 1.038 2.051 1.577 4.624 2.479 7.395 2.407 0.543-0.015 0.976-0.457 0.976-1v-1.011c-0.002-0.179 0.009-0.357 0.034-0.533 0.113-0.806 0.504-1.569 1.162-2.141 0.725-0.631 1.636-0.908 2.526-0.846s1.753 0.463 2.384 1.188c0.252 0.286 0.649 0.416 1.033 0.304 0.231-0.067 0.463-0.143 0.695-0.228zM22.424 2.183c-0.74 0.522-1.523 0.926-2.287 1.205-0.931-0.836-2.091-1.302-3.276-1.385-1.398-0.097-2.836 0.339-3.977 1.332-1.036 0.901-1.652 2.108-1.83 3.372-0.037 0.265-0.055 0.532-0.054 0.8-1.922-0.142-3.693-0.85-5.15-1.97-0.775-0.596-1.462-1.309-2.034-2.116-0.32-0.45-0.944-0.557-1.394-0.237-0.154 0.109-0.267 0.253-0.335 0.409 0 0-0.132 0.299-0.285 0.76-0.112 0.337-0.241 0.775-0.357 1.29-0.163 0.722-0.302 1.602-0.326 2.571-0.031 1.227 0.12 2.612 0.652 3.996 0.683 1.775 1.966 3.478 4.147 4.823-1.569 0.726-3.245 1.039-4.873 0.967-0.552-0.024-1.019 0.403-1.043 0.955-0.017 0.389 0.19 0.736 0.513 0.918 4.905 2.725 10.426 2.678 14.666 0.261 4.040-2.301 6.819-6.7 6.819-12.634-0.001-0.167-0.008-0.33-0.023-0.489 1.006-1.115 1.676-2.429 1.996-3.781 0.127-0.537-0.206-1.076-0.743-1.203-0.29-0.069-0.58-0.003-0.807 0.156z"
  ></path>
</svg>
<p class="handle">@kintay8</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bootstrap or use it like this it will solve your issue

```css
.container{
display :flex
}

.instagram, .twitter{
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
}
p.ig, p.handle{

font-size: 120%;
    font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="instagram">
              <svg id="ig" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
              <title>instagram1</title>
              <path d="M16 2.881c4.275 0 4.781 0.019 6.462 0.094 1.563 0.069 2.406 0.331 2.969 0.55 0.744 0.288 1.281 0.638 1.837 1.194 0.563 0.563 0.906 1.094 1.2 1.838 0.219 0.563 0.481 1.412 0.55 2.969 0.075 1.688 0.094 2.194 0.094 6.463s-0.019 4.781-0.094 6.463c-0.069 1.563-0.331 2.406-0.55 2.969-0.288 0.744-0.637 1.281-1.194 1.837-0.563 0.563-1.094 0.906-1.837 1.2-0.563 0.219-1.413 0.481-2.969 0.55-1.688 0.075-2.194 0.094-6.463 0.094s-4.781-0.019-6.463-0.094c-1.563-0.069-2.406-0.331-2.969-0.55-0.744-0.288-1.281-0.637-1.838-1.194-0.563-0.563-0.906-1.094-1.2-1.837-0.219-0.563-0.481-1.413-0.55-2.969-0.075-1.688-0.094-2.194-0.094-6.463s0.019-4.781 0.094-6.463c0.069-1.563 0.331-2.406 0.55-2.969 0.288-0.744 0.638-1.281 1.194-1.838 0.563-0.563 1.094-0.906 1.838-1.2 0.563-0.219 1.412-0.481 2.969-0.55 1.681-0.075 2.188-0.094 6.463-0.094zM16 0c-4.344 0-4.887 0.019-6.594 0.094-1.7 0.075-2.869 0.35-3.881 0.744-1.056 0.412-1.95 0.956-2.837 1.85-0.894 0.888-1.438 1.781-1.85 2.831-0.394 1.019-0.669 2.181-0.744 3.881-0.075 1.713-0.094 2.256-0.094 6.6s0.019 4.887 0.094 6.594c0.075 1.7 0.35 2.869 0.744 3.881 0.413 1.056 0.956 1.95 1.85 2.837 0.887 0.887 1.781 1.438 2.831 1.844 1.019 0.394 2.181 0.669 3.881 0.744 1.706 0.075 2.25 0.094 6.594 0.094s4.888-0.019 6.594-0.094c1.7-0.075 2.869-0.35 3.881-0.744 1.050-0.406 1.944-0.956 2.831-1.844s1.438-1.781 1.844-2.831c0.394-1.019 0.669-2.181 0.744-3.881 0.075-1.706 0.094-2.25 0.094-6.594s-0.019-4.887-0.094-6.594c-0.075-1.7-0.35-2.869-0.744-3.881-0.394-1.063-0.938-1.956-1.831-2.844-0.887-0.887-1.781-1.438-2.831-1.844-1.019-0.394-2.181-0.669-3.881-0.744-1.712-0.081-2.256-0.1-6.6-0.1v0z"></path>
                                  <path d="M16 7.781c-4.537 0-8.219 3.681-8.219 8.219s3.681 8.219 8.219 8.219 8.219-3.681 8.219-8.219c0-4.537-3.681-8.219-8.219-8.219zM16 21.331c-2.944 0-5.331-2.387-5.331-5.331s2.387-5.331 5.331-5.331c2.944 0 5.331 2.387 5.331 5.331s-2.387 5.331-5.331 5.331z"></path>
                                  <path d="M26.462 7.456c0 1.060-0.859 1.919-1.919 1.919s-1.919-0.859-1.919-1.919c0-1.060 0.859-1.919 1.919-1.919s1.919 0.859 1.919 1.919z"></path>
                              </svg>
                              <p class="ig">annoying_fly</p>

          </div>
          <div class="twitter">
                     <svg class="twitter" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                     <title>twitter</title>
                     <path d="M20.833 5.262c-0.186 0.242-0.391 0.475-0.616 0.696-0.233 0.232-0.347 0.567-0.278 0.908 0.037 0.182 0.060 0.404 0.061 0.634 0 5.256-2.429 8.971-5.81 10.898-2.647 1.509-5.938 1.955-9.222 1.12 1.245-0.361 2.46-0.921 3.593-1.69 0.147-0.099 0.273-0.243 0.352-0.421 0.224-0.505-0.003-1.096-0.508-1.32-2.774-1.233-4.13-2.931-4.769-4.593-0.417-1.084-0.546-2.198-0.52-3.227 0.021-0.811 0.138-1.56 0.278-2.182 0.394 0.343 0.803 0.706 1.235 1.038 2.051 1.577 4.624 2.479 7.395 2.407 0.543-0.015 0.976-0.457 0.976-1v-1.011c-0.002-0.179 0.009-0.357 0.034-0.533 0.113-0.806 0.504-1.569 1.162-2.141 0.725-0.631 1.636-0.908 2.526-0.846s1.753 0.463 2.384 1.188c0.252 0.286 0.649 0.416 1.033 0.304 0.231-0.067 0.463-0.143 0.695-0.228zM22.424 2.183c-0.74 0.522-1.523 0.926-2.287 1.205-0.931-0.836-2.091-1.302-3.276-1.385-1.398-0.097-2.836 0.339-3.977 1.332-1.036 0.901-1.652 2.108-1.83 3.372-0.037 0.265-0.055 0.532-0.054 0.8-1.922-0.142-3.693-0.85-5.15-1.97-0.775-0.596-1.462-1.309-2.034-2.116-0.32-0.45-0.944-0.557-1.394-0.237-0.154 0.109-0.267 0.253-0.335 0.409 0 0-0.132 0.299-0.285 0.76-0.112 0.337-0.241 0.775-0.357 1.29-0.163 0.722-0.302 1.602-0.326 2.571-0.031 1.227 0.12 2.612 0.652 3.996 0.683 1.775 1.966 3.478 4.147 4.823-1.569 0.726-3.245 1.039-4.873 0.967-0.552-0.024-1.019 0.403-1.043 0.955-0.017 0.389 0.19 0.736 0.513 0.918 4.905 2.725 10.426 2.678 14.666 0.261 4.040-2.301 6.819-6.7 6.819-12.634-0.001-0.167-0.008-0.33-0.023-0.489 1.006-1.115 1.676-2.429 1.996-3.781 0.127-0.537-0.206-1.076-0.743-1.203-0.29-0.069-0.58-0.003-0.807 0.156z"></path>
                              </svg>
                              <p class="handle">@kintay8</p>

                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see your svgs but their positioning is not correct. You have 2 options. One option is to position them absolute as you have already done and they will be responsive if you use vw for margin top and margin left (in my opinion you should you top and left or bottom and right instead of margin as you position them absolute) or you put them in a flex container in order to be in the same row

Answer (score 0):

Check this. hope it helps.
You don't have to add absolute. A simple HTML structure could solve your problem.

```css
.social-networks{display:inline-block; width:250px; text-align:center}

#ig {
        margin:0 auto
    }
    
    .ig {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        font-size: 120%;
        font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .twitter {
         margin:0 auto
    }
    
    .handle {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 120%;
        font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<div class="social-networks">
<svg id="ig" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <title>instagram1</title>
                    <path d="M16 2.881c4.275 0 4.781 0.019 6.462 0.094 1.563 0.069 2.406 0.331 2.969 0.55 0.744 0.288 1.281 0.638 1.837 1.194 0.563 0.563 0.906 1.094 1.2 1.838 0.219 0.563 0.481 1.412 0.55 2.969 0.075 1.688 0.094 2.194 0.094 6.463s-0.019 4.781-0.094 6.463c-0.069 1.563-0.331 2.406-0.55 2.969-0.288 0.744-0.637 1.281-1.194 1.837-0.563 0.563-1.094 0.906-1.837 1.2-0.563 0.219-1.413 0.481-2.969 0.55-1.688 0.075-2.194 0.094-6.463 0.094s-4.781-0.019-6.463-0.094c-1.563-0.069-2.406-0.331-2.969-0.55-0.744-0.288-1.281-0.637-1.838-1.194-0.563-0.563-0.906-1.094-1.2-1.837-0.219-0.563-0.481-1.413-0.55-2.969-0.075-1.688-0.094-2.194-0.094-6.463s0.019-4.781 0.094-6.463c0.069-1.563 0.331-2.406 0.55-2.969 0.288-0.744 0.638-1.281 1.194-1.838 0.563-0.563 1.094-0.906 1.838-1.2 0.563-0.219 1.412-0.481 2.969-0.55 1.681-0.075 2.188-0.094 6.463-0.094zM16 0c-4.344 0-4.887 0.019-6.594 0.094-1.7 0.075-2.869 0.35-3.881 0.744-1.056 0.412-1.95 0.956-2.837 1.85-0.894 0.888-1.438 1.781-1.85 2.831-0.394 1.019-0.669 2.181-0.744 3.881-0.075 1.713-0.094 2.256-0.094 6.6s0.019 4.887 0.094 6.594c0.075 1.7 0.35 2.869 0.744 3.881 0.413 1.056 0.956 1.95 1.85 2.837 0.887 0.887 1.781 1.438 2.831 1.844 1.019 0.394 2.181 0.669 3.881 0.744 1.706 0.075 2.25 0.094 6.594 0.094s4.888-0.019 6.594-0.094c1.7-0.075 2.869-0.35 3.881-0.744 1.050-0.406 1.944-0.956 2.831-1.844s1.438-1.781 1.844-2.831c0.394-1.019 0.669-2.181 0.744-3.881 0.075-1.706 0.094-2.25 0.094-6.594s-0.019-4.887-0.094-6.594c-0.075-1.7-0.35-2.869-0.744-3.881-0.394-1.063-0.938-1.956-1.831-2.844-0.887-0.887-1.781-1.438-2.831-1.844-1.019-0.394-2.181-0.669-3.881-0.744-1.712-0.081-2.256-0.1-6.6-0.1v0z"></path>
                    <path d="M16 7.781c-4.537 0-8.219 3.681-8.219 8.219s3.681 8.219 8.219 8.219 8.219-3.681 8.219-8.219c0-4.537-3.681-8.219-8.219-8.219zM16 21.331c-2.944 0-5.331-2.387-5.331-5.331s2.387-5.331 5.331-5.331c2.944 0 5.331 2.387 5.331 5.331s-2.387 5.331-5.331 5.331z"></path>
                    <path d="M26.462 7.456c0 1.060-0.859 1.919-1.919 1.919s-1.919-0.859-1.919-1.919c0-1.060 0.859-1.919 1.919-1.919s1.919 0.859 1.919 1.919z"></path>
                </svg>
                <p class="ig">annoying_fly</p>
                </div>
                <div class="social-networks">
                <svg class="twitter" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <title>twitter</title>
                    <path d="M20.833 5.262c-0.186 0.242-0.391 0.475-0.616 0.696-0.233 0.232-0.347 0.567-0.278 0.908 0.037 0.182 0.060 0.404 0.061 0.634 0 5.256-2.429 8.971-5.81 10.898-2.647 1.509-5.938 1.955-9.222 1.12 1.245-0.361 2.46-0.921 3.593-1.69 0.147-0.099 0.273-0.243 0.352-0.421 0.224-0.505-0.003-1.096-0.508-1.32-2.774-1.233-4.13-2.931-4.769-4.593-0.417-1.084-0.546-2.198-0.52-3.227 0.021-0.811 0.138-1.56 0.278-2.182 0.394 0.343 0.803 0.706 1.235 1.038 2.051 1.577 4.624 2.479 7.395 2.407 0.543-0.015 0.976-0.457 0.976-1v-1.011c-0.002-0.179 0.009-0.357 0.034-0.533 0.113-0.806 0.504-1.569 1.162-2.141 0.725-0.631 1.636-0.908 2.526-0.846s1.753 0.463 2.384 1.188c0.252 0.286 0.649 0.416 1.033 0.304 0.231-0.067 0.463-0.143 0.695-0.228zM22.424 2.183c-0.74 0.522-1.523 0.926-2.287 1.205-0.931-0.836-2.091-1.302-3.276-1.385-1.398-0.097-2.836 0.339-3.977 1.332-1.036 0.901-1.652 2.108-1.83 3.372-0.037 0.265-0.055 0.532-0.054 0.8-1.922-0.142-3.693-0.85-5.15-1.97-0.775-0.596-1.462-1.309-2.034-2.116-0.32-0.45-0.944-0.557-1.394-0.237-0.154 0.109-0.267 0.253-0.335 0.409 0 0-0.132 0.299-0.285 0.76-0.112 0.337-0.241 0.775-0.357 1.29-0.163 0.722-0.302 1.602-0.326 2.571-0.031 1.227 0.12 2.612 0.652 3.996 0.683 1.775 1.966 3.478 4.147 4.823-1.569 0.726-3.245 1.039-4.873 0.967-0.552-0.024-1.019 0.403-1.043 0.955-0.017 0.389 0.19 0.736 0.513 0.918 4.905 2.725 10.426 2.678 14.666 0.261 4.040-2.301 6.819-6.7 6.819-12.634-0.001-0.167-0.008-0.33-0.023-0.489 1.006-1.115 1.676-2.429 1.996-3.781 0.127-0.537-0.206-1.076-0.743-1.203-0.29-0.069-0.58-0.003-0.807 0.156z"></path>
                </svg>
                <p class="handle">@kintay8</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Out:

HTML:

```
<div id="about-me">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
  <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
   <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>

      <h1>Things I Offer</h1>
  <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
   <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
<div id="socials-container">
<div id="instagram">
<svg id="ig" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <title>instagram1</title>
                    <path d="M16 2.881c4.275 0 4.781 0.019 6.462 0.094 1.563 0.069 2.406 0.331 2.969 0.55 0.744 0.288 1.281 0.638 1.837 1.194 0.563 0.563 0.906 1.094 1.2 1.838 0.219 0.563 0.481 1.412 0.55 2.969 0.075 1.688 0.094 2.194 0.094 6.463s-0.019 4.781-0.094 6.463c-0.069 1.563-0.331 2.406-0.55 2.969-0.288 0.744-0.637 1.281-1.194 1.837-0.563 0.563-1.094 0.906-1.837 1.2-0.563 0.219-1.413 0.481-2.969 0.55-1.688 0.075-2.194 0.094-6.463 0.094s-4.781-0.019-6.463-0.094c-1.563-0.069-2.406-0.331-2.969-0.55-0.744-0.288-1.281-0.637-1.838-1.194-0.563-0.563-0.906-1.094-1.2-1.837-0.219-0.563-0.481-1.413-0.55-2.969-0.075-1.688-0.094-2.194-0.094-6.463s0.019-4.781 0.094-6.463c0.069-1.563 0.331-2.406 0.55-2.969 0.288-0.744 0.638-1.281 1.194-1.838 0.563-0.563 1.094-0.906 1.838-1.2 0.563-0.219 1.412-0.481 2.969-0.55 1.681-0.075 2.188-0.094 6.463-0.094zM16 0c-4.344 0-4.887 0.019-6.594 0.094-1.7 0.075-2.869 0.35-3.881 0.744-1.056 0.412-1.95 0.956-2.837 1.85-0.894 0.888-1.438 1.781-1.85 2.831-0.394 1.019-0.669 2.181-0.744 3.881-0.075 1.713-0.094 2.256-0.094 6.6s0.019 4.887 0.094 6.594c0.075 1.7 0.35 2.869 0.744 3.881 0.413 1.056 0.956 1.95 1.85 2.837 0.887 0.887 1.781 1.438 2.831 1.844 1.019 0.394 2.181 0.669 3.881 0.744 1.706 0.075 2.25 0.094 6.594 0.094s4.888-0.019 6.594-0.094c1.7-0.075 2.869-0.35 3.881-0.744 1.050-0.406 1.944-0.956 2.831-1.844s1.438-1.781 1.844-2.831c0.394-1.019 0.669-2.181 0.744-3.881 0.075-1.706 0.094-2.25 0.094-6.594s-0.019-4.887-0.094-6.594c-0.075-1.7-0.35-2.869-0.744-3.881-0.394-1.063-0.938-1.956-1.831-2.844-0.887-0.887-1.781-1.438-2.831-1.844-1.019-0.394-2.181-0.669-3.881-0.744-1.712-0.081-2.256-0.1-6.6-0.1v0z"></path>
                    <path d="M16 7.781c-4.537 0-8.219 3.681-8.219 8.219s3.681 8.219 8.219 8.219 8.219-3.681 8.219-8.219c0-4.537-3.681-8.219-8.219-8.219zM16 21.331c-2.944 0-5.331-2.387-5.331-5.331s2.387-5.331 5.331-5.331c2.944 0 5.331 2.387 5.331 5.331s-2.387 5.331-5.331 5.331z"></path>
                    <path d="M26.462 7.456c0 1.060-0.859 1.919-1.919 1.919s-1.919-0.859-1.919-1.919c0-1.060 0.859-1.919 1.919-1.919s1.919 0.859 1.919 1.919z"></path>
                </svg>

                <p class="ig">annoying_fly</p>

</div>

    <div id="twitter-box">
                <svg id="twitter" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">


                    <title>twitter</title>
                    <path d="M20.833 5.262c-0.186 0.242-0.391 0.475-0.616 0.696-0.233 0.232-0.347 0.567-0.278 0.908 0.037 0.182 0.060 0.404 0.061 0.634 0 5.256-2.429 8.971-5.81 10.898-2.647 1.509-5.938 1.955-9.222 1.12 1.245-0.361 2.46-0.921 3.593-1.69 0.147-0.099 0.273-0.243 0.352-0.421 0.224-0.505-0.003-1.096-0.508-1.32-2.774-1.233-4.13-2.931-4.769-4.593-0.417-1.084-0.546-2.198-0.52-3.227 0.021-0.811 0.138-1.56 0.278-2.182 0.394 0.343 0.803 0.706 1.235 1.038 2.051 1.577 4.624 2.479 7.395 2.407 0.543-0.015 0.976-0.457 0.976-1v-1.011c-0.002-0.179 0.009-0.357 0.034-0.533 0.113-0.806 0.504-1.569 1.162-2.141 0.725-0.631 1.636-0.908 2.526-0.846s1.753 0.463 2.384 1.188c0.252 0.286 0.649 0.416 1.033 0.304 0.231-0.067 0.463-0.143 0.695-0.228zM22.424 2.183c-0.74 0.522-1.523 0.926-2.287 1.205-0.931-0.836-2.091-1.302-3.276-1.385-1.398-0.097-2.836 0.339-3.977 1.332-1.036 0.901-1.652 2.108-1.83 3.372-0.037 0.265-0.055 0.532-0.054 0.8-1.922-0.142-3.693-0.85-5.15-1.97-0.775-0.596-1.462-1.309-2.034-2.116-0.32-0.45-0.944-0.557-1.394-0.237-0.154 0.109-0.267 0.253-0.335 0.409 0 0-0.132 0.299-0.285 0.76-0.112 0.337-0.241 0.775-0.357 1.29-0.163 0.722-0.302 1.602-0.326 2.571-0.031 1.227 0.12 2.612 0.652 3.996 0.683 1.775 1.966 3.478 4.147 4.823-1.569 0.726-3.245 1.039-4.873 0.967-0.552-0.024-1.019 0.403-1.043 0.955-0.017 0.389 0.19 0.736 0.513 0.918 4.905 2.725 10.426 2.678 14.666 0.261 4.040-2.301 6.819-6.7 6.819-12.634-0.001-0.167-0.008-0.33-0.023-0.489 1.006-1.115 1.676-2.429 1.996-3.781 0.127-0.537-0.206-1.076-0.743-1.203-0.29-0.069-0.58-0.003-0.807 0.156z"></path>
                </svg>
                <p class="handle">@kintay8</p>
</div>


</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
   #about-me {
      background-color: #ccc;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      items-align: center;
      width: 80vw;
      margin-left: 10vw;
    }

    #socials-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 50vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #instagram {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100px;
    }

    #twitter-box {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100px;
    }


    .ig,  .handle {
            font-family: "Lobster", sans-serif;
     }
```